# C++ random number generators legacy code

Tags: c++, c++11, random, standards, incompatibility

I've got some older code which uses `std::uniform_int` and `std::variate_generator`. On one machine I use GCC 4.8.5 and it works pretty fine. On my newer workstation I have GCC 7.2.1 installed and it is not possible to compile the code.

The error message is, that `uniform_int` and `variate_generator` are not members of `std`. I found some information that in newer C++ standards they are not supported anymore and for `uniform_int` `uniform_int_distribution` should be used.

Is there any possibility to extend the code that it will work on both machine. For example to use some "adapter-code" to rebuild the interface of `uniform_int_distribution` to `uniform_int`?

Comment: as far as I recall, that's based on older boost.random. So, you may try finding the last boost version supporting it and use it as a drop-in replacement instead ...

Comment: indeed, it looks like [boost1.47](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_47_0.html) synchronized with the standard version; anyway, if I read the release notes correctly, there are ready-made wrappers for your use case ...

Comment: I had a similar issue when compiling with g++ 7.2.0. I was missing an include to <random>